# Give Laravel variable to mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, laravel, triggers, laravel-8

How can I pass this Laravel variable to trigger?

```
public function up()
    {
        $slots = config('example.slots');
        DB::unprepared('
        CREATE TRIGGER tr_Example AFTER INSERT ON `example_table` FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
            declare x int DEFAULT 1;
                WHILE x < $slots DO
                    INSERT INTO example_example_table (`example_id`, `title`, `description`) 
                    VALUES (NEW.id, " ", " ");
                    SET x=x+1;
                END WHILE;
            END
        ');
    }
```

I want to pass this slots variable to the trigger. How can I do that?

Comment: You can add `trigger` in your database.

Comment: What?I want to use the $slots variable in trigger.

Comment: Exactly where you want to use `$slots` variable in the trigger?

Comment: WHILE x < $slots DO     <- here . $slots  is a number, so in example I want to WHILE x < $slots (ex. 40).